# passing values from drop down list and text box to JavaScript in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, dwr

[image]I am trying to pass two values to a JavaScript one that I obtain from a dropdown list, and the other one is user specified from a text box, I have the following in my JSP file:

```
<select id="selectLine">
    <c:forEach var="line" items="${availableLines}">
        <option value="${line}">${line}</option>
    </c:forEach>
<select>
<label> Extension number to add </label>
<input type="text" name="extNum" />
<button onclick="insertDN();">Insert</button>
```

And I also have a java script that uses DWR to pass the values to a a Java class called DBOps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertDN(){

     var selectedLine = document.getElementById("selectLine").value;
     var selectedExt = document.getElementById("extNum").value;
     DBOps.insertDN(selectedLine, selectedExt);

    }
```

The first one for "selectedLine" works fine by itself and it does pass the correct value to the function, but the second one is not "selectedExt". Also when I put both of them together the first one refuses to work. What am I doing wrong here? help please?

Comment: Just a heads up, using something like jQuery will make your life a whole lot easier...

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getElementByID` but `<input type="text" name="extNum" />` doesn't have an ID.

Comment: I have tried both name and Id attributes, I have read that get interpreted the same in this situation. but I have tried both and neither works

Comment: @user2247823 when updating your page, make sure that the generated HTML also gets updated. Probably you're testing it on IE and the results are being cached. To test this, just view the sources of your page and make sure the `<input type="text" name="extNum" />` has the right id.

Comment: it does have the right ID but still it does not read it correctly in teh javascript

Answer (score 0):

you didnt use id in your text field but you are using **getElementById**..

Instead use getElementByTagName to

Comment: I tried both getElementByName and getElementById, both not passing the correct value